# How to play video recorded with varbinary in c # win form database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I uploaded a video to the database with varbinary. I want to play this video in my c# win form. But I don't know their code.

Comment: Will this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20173448/retrieve-video-file-stored-as-varbinary-in-sql-server-express-database

Answer (score 1):

Following is the snippet for getting the file from database and play it.

```
private string GetFromDataBase(string fileName)
{
   SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        String Query1 = "SELECT FileData FROM [Test].[dbo].[MyPlay] where FileName = '" + fileName + "'";
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Query1, ConnectionString);
        DataSet Ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(Ds, "MyPlay");
        if (Ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No data Found");
            return string.Empty;
        }
        return ConvertByteDataToFile(fileName, GetUnCompressedData((byte[])Ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FileData"]));
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```